How can i programmatically open the editor on a file from a jar, in an eclipse rcp application?
In my eclispe rcp application I have a custom view similar to project explorer. I am trying to open a file from a jar, similar to the way you would open the editor if you would go in Project Explorer > Maven Dependencies > expand the jar and double click on the file. I looked at the available code on github for eclipse.platform.ui and m2e-core but I can not find the code which does this specific operation.
So far i've tried :
//IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(IPath.fromOSString(path));

//IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getStore(URI.create(path));
//FileStoreEditorInput fsei = new FileStoreEditorInput(fileStore);
//IDE.openEditor(page, fsei, "myDsl.editor.id", linkingActive);

IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getStore(URI.create(path));
IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);

and
IDE.openEditor(page, URI.create(path), "myDsl.editor.id", true);
but I get : The system can not find the path specified.
Currently I am passing the path in the following format :
file:/C:/Users/user.name/pathToJar/myDsl.jar!/myDslFile.myDsl
adding "jar:" at the begging does not help, nor removing the ! after the .jar
I know there would be an option to unzip the jar and open it like this, but I would rather use a similar method to the way you can open files from maven dependencies from project explorer. Any ideas on what am I missing?

Since it is a Jar it will be handled by JDT, probably org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JarEntryEditorInput which is internal so should not be used directly. org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction and org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility seem to be the main things to look at.

Note: I worked this out using Eclipse "Menu Spy" to see what the Open action on a jar entry called (in this case the OpenAction mentioned above)

An alternative might be to write your own IStorageEditorInput editor input and read the jar entry yourself.
